# GraalVM installation directory not found

Tags: gluon, graalvm

On MacOS 10.15.5, running IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.2.2.

I am trying to build a test project with Gluon using GraalVM via the [client-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-gradle-plugin)(0.1.32). I've followed all the setup listed in the README and GraalVM's docs as follows:

- Download the latest GraalVM for mac from [here](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/tag/vm-20.2.0)
- Unpack the tar and sudo mv it to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
- Added the following to .zshrc:

  > export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0/Contents/Home/bin
  >
  > export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0/Contents/Home
  >
  > export GRAALVM_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
- Set my Project SDK to point to the same place as $GRAALVM_HOME (not sure this was needed?)

My project builds and runs just fine on the desktop, but I am now trying to target iOS. I got to the point where it was trying to find my iOS sdk so I was double checking my XCode setup to try and connect the dots.

Suddenly, when running `sudo ./gradlew build nativeBuild` I started getting the same error I had been stuck on for a long time:

> GraalVM installation directory not found. Either set GRAALVM_HOME as an environment variable or set graalvmHome in the client-plugin configuration

If I `echo $GRAALVM_HOME` I get /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0/Contents/Home so things seem like they're set up correctly. I've tried to reset everything from the IDE, the computer, the GraalVM install and I can't come up with a way to get back to where my `nativeBuild` gets past this point.

Comment: I assume you run the native tasks from a terminal. If you open a new terminal, and run `./gradlew clean nativeBuild`, does it work? (`sudo` shouldn't be necessary) If it doesn't, in the same terminal print your `PATH`, and see if you might have old invalid paths.

Comment: I think I got into a weird situation where the gradle daemon had locked some generated files and so it wouldn't run clean properly. So naturally I tried to brute force it by sudo-ing stuff. This put all the files in a weird state. I removed all my generated files manually, killed all the gradle daemons, and followed your advice and things worked out. Thanks for the help!